# Python UUID represented as special characters

Tags: python, algorithm, uuid, transpose, isomorphism

When creating a UUID in Python, likeso:

```
>>> uuid.uuid1()
UUID('a8098c1a-f86e-11da-bd1a-00112444be1e')
```

How could one map that UUID into a string made up of the capitalized alphabet A-Z minus the characters D, F, I, O, Q, and U, plus the numerical digits, plus the characters "+" and "=". i.e. the from an integer or string onto the set of 32 (relatively OCR friendly) characters:

```
[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ1234567890+=]
```

I'll call this the `OCRf` set (for OCR friendly).

I'd like to have an isomorphic function:

```
def uuid_to_ocr_friendly_chars(uid)
    """takes uid, an integer, and transposes it into a string made 
       of the the OCRf set
    """
    ...
```

My first thought is to go through the process of changing the uuid to base 32. e.g.

```
OCRf = "ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ1234567890+="

def uuid_to_ocr_friendly_chars(uid):
     ocfstr = ''
     while uid > 1:
        ocfstr += OCRf[uid % 32]
        uid /= 32
     return ocfstr
```

However, I'd like to know if this method is the best and fastest way to go about this conversion - or if there's a simpler and faster method (e.g. a builtin, a smarter algorithm, or just a better method).

I'm grateful for your input. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How important is it to you to "squeeze" the representation by 18.75%, i.e., from 32 to 26 characters?  Because, if saving this small percentage of bytes isn't absolutely crucial,  something like `uid.hex.upper().replace('D','Z')` will do what you ask (not using the whole alphabet you make available, but the only cost of this is missing that 18.75% "squeezing").

If squeezing down every last byte is crucial, I'd work on substrings of 20 bits each -- that's 5 hex characters, 4 characters in your funky alphabet.  There are 6 of those (plus 8 bits left over, for which you can take the `hex.upper().replace` as above since there's nothing to gain in doing anything fancier).  You can easily get the substrings by slicing `.hex` and turn each into an int with an `int(theslice, 16)`.  Then, you can basically apply the same algorithm you're using above -- but the arithmetic is all done on much-smaller numbers, so the speed gain should be material.  Also, don't build the string by looping on `+=` -- make a list of all the "digits", and `''.join` them all at the end -- that's also a performance improvement.

Comment: Agree re. space queezing- good point - though there's an (astronomically remote) possibility of collisions with a .replace('O','D')/etc. The more important point would be to have a reduced, albeit "funky", alphabet that uses fewer visually ambiguous characters (e.g. "D","O","Q", and "0").

Comment: @Brian, I don't see what "collisions" could occur if you just use `uid.hex.upper().replace('D', 'Z')`.  'D' is the only character in the hex set potentially confusable with another ('0', the digit zero)

Comment: Oh sorry -- I was thinking the algorithm suggested in the second paragraph would apply `replace('D','Z')` to the 20 bit substrings.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> OCRf = 'ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ1234567890+='
>>> uuid = 'a8098c1a-f86e-11da-bd1a-00112444be1e'
>>> binstr = bin(int(uuid.replace("-",""),16))[2:].zfill(130)
>>> ocfstr = "".join(OCRf[int(binstr[i:i+5],2)] for i in range(0,130,5))
>>> ocfstr
'HLBJJB2+ETCKSP7JWACGYGMVW+'
```

To convert back again

```
>>> "%x"%(int("".join(bin(OCRf.index(i))[2:].zfill(5) for i in ocfstr),2))
'a8098c1af86e11dabd1a00112444be1e'
```

Comment: There's no need for the fanciness with binstr - you can just fetch the .bytes property on a UUID to get its binary representation.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, Can you explain what you mean? I don't see how I can regroup the `.bytes` as base 32

Comment: Just encode it using base32, or any of the other encoding schemes suggested here. My point is that if you have a real UUID object, the third line of your snippet can be replaced with just "uuid.bytes".

Answer (score 1):

```
transtbl = string.maketrans(
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567',
  'ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ1234567890+='
)

uuidstr = uuid.uuid1()

print base64.b32encode(str(uuidstr).replace('-', '').decode('hex')).rstrip('=').translate(transtbl)
```

Yes, this method *does* make me a bit ill, thanks for asking.